# How to run an extracted jar?

Tags: java, jar

If I extract a Jar file into a directory, what's the correct java command to run it as if it was the jar?

Meaning, what would be the equivalent command to `java -jar myProgram.jar` except not using the jar itself?

I've tried stuff like `java -cp ".;META-INF\lib\*" JarMain` but it seems like there's still something missing there.

Comment: Which OS are you using? windows/*nix?

Comment: How do you know "still something missing"? What exactly happens? Error Message, misbehaviour?

Comment: Using Windows. It errors out when I try to run the extracted jar: `ERROR: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file` `ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException` which doesn't happen when I run the jar version.There's a lot of stuff going on in there so I have no idea where this error is coming from, but I figured it was an issue with me not reconstructing the classpath properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you run jar file directly (without extracting), you can use command: **java -jar jarfilename. jar**
If you extract jar file into separated files, you can run .class file only. Use the command **java classfilename**.
You need to set path environment to java/bin directory before running above commands, or just change directory to it.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question and gives wrong information. `java` doesn't​ take a class file name argument but a class name argument, said class to have a `static void main(String)` method. It is also bad advice to suggest  changing directory to the `$JAVA_HOME/bin` directory to run Java, and it's not relevant.

Comment: Why wrong ? The file name and class name need to be same. I said that is not wrong. For charging class path or directory, it will help you perform command without indicating absolute path. The command I typed has only file name!!!

Comment: One more, for Java 1.7 and above, you need run class from main, but less than 1.7, you can run it without main. Just nothing will be showed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that add a jar to classpath but do not run it? If so, `java -cp myProgram.jar;ohterjar/libdir JarMain`. If you use linux/mac,replace ; to :.